# Creating a simple configuration file and parser in C

Tags: c, file, parsing, configuration

I created a configuration file like this

`smartphones = 50;
 laptops = 30;
 watches = 20;`

when the program runs, I would like it to load the configuration settings into the programs variables listed below.

`int smartphones, laptops, watches;`

Thanks!

EDIT: 
There is a test that I did to parse the text in my configuration file. Anyway I think that the code isn't good. Suggestions?

`int count = 0;`

`int flag = 0, more = 0;`

`int sphones = 0, laptops=0, watches=0;`
`

```
     if((fp = fopen("filecfg.txt","r")) != NULL){while(fgets(bufr,MAXLINE,fp)!=NULL){
       `    count +=1;`
            if(flag==0){
                for (int k = 0; bufr[k] != '\0'; k++){
                    if (isdigit(bufr[k])){
                        if(more==1){
                            sphones *= 10;
                            sphones += bufr[k] - '0';   
                        } else {    
                            sphones = bufr[k] - '0'; 
                            more=1;
                        }
                    }   
              }
              flag = 1;
        }else if(flag==1){
            for (int k = 0; bufr[k] != '\0'; k++){
                if (isdigit(bufr[k])){
                    if(more==1){
                        laptops *= 10;
                        laptops += bufr[k] - '0';   
                    } else {    
                        laptops = bufr[k] - '0'; 
                        more=1;
                    }
                }   
            } 
            flag = 2;
        }else if(flag==2){
            for (int k = 0; bufr[k] != '\0'; k++){
                if (isdigit(bufr[k])){
                    if(more==1){
                        watches *= 10;
                        watches += bufr[k] - '0';   
                    } else {    
                        watches = bufr[k] - '0';
                        more=1;
                    }
                }
            }       
            flag = 3;   
        }
```

Comment: what is the type of configuration file? text file?

Comment: Please ask *specific* questions about *specific* problems. Don't just expect us to write code for you.

Comment: You should show some effort. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Makes no sense? How do you load configuration settings into `int` variables? That is my question: would love to know.

Comment: Yes, it's a text file.

Comment: @DarkKnight I made a little code but I think it's not functional. How can I show you the code?

Comment: Edit your post and add in the code

Comment: That looks like c++ not c#

Answer (score 2):

This answer is in C# and is being left here for posterity. The original title and tag of the question was C# and not C.

```
string config = File.ReadAllText("config_file");

var values = config.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var value in values)
{
    var pair = value.Split("=",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var key = pair[0].Trim();
    var val = Convert.ToInt32(pair[1].Trim());
    dict[key] = val;
}

int smartphones = dict[nameof(smartphones)];
```

Comment: I'm downvoting because the question was for the C language, but your proposed solution is for a different language.

Comment: The question was originally titled and tagged with C#. So my answer was a C# answer. It wasn't until he posted actual source code that I asked the question about what language he actually meant.

Comment: I have removed my down vote, based on Rabid Penguin's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have txt file with your configuration entries, this is how you do it.

```
var configEntries = File.ReadAllLines("Path/To/YourFile");
int smartphones = int.Parse(configEntries.First(x=>x.Replace(";","")
                                                    .Contains("smartphones"))
                                                    .Split(' ')[1].Trim());
//Repeat same for other 2 variables.
```

Comment: I'm downvoting because the question was for the C language, but your proposed solution is for a different language.

Comment: @CiaranMcHale : It would have made much sense if you have taken a look at edit history of question. Not one , but two of us here wrote answer in c#. I wish that had made you to think twice at least before downvoting. Ask for assistance if you don't know how SO works. THE QUESTION WAS TITLED AND TAGGED WITH C# ORIGINALLY.

Comment: I've upvoted to remove the @Ciaran McHale's downvote. DarkKnight is correct and this question was originally titled and tagged C#.

Comment: I tried to remove my down vote, based on Rabid Penguin's comment, but StackOverflow won't let me. Apparently, my down vote is "locked in".